# Composite Key for Gizmo Tracking

Tags: sql-server, database-design, identity

I'm trying to setup a many to many relationship between an gizmo table and a owner table.

- A owner can have many gizmos
- And a gizmo can have many owners

When I have a linking table do I set the gizmoID and ownerID as a composite key and then set the foreign keys on the gizmo table to Identity Auto-Increment by 1 and the same on the owner table or do I set composite key to identity auto-increment.

I am working on sql server 2014 Express and fairly new to this and trying to wrap my head around this.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it will have three table

1. one table for Owner,  Identity Auto-Increment by 1 will give OwnerId
2. one table for gizmos, Identity Auto-Increment by 1 will give gizmosId
3. One table for mapping the many to many relationship as

   `OwnerId - FK`
   `gizmosId - FK` and 
    `Other columns`

Now as the combination of OwnerId and gizmosId will make a row unique you can create primary key constraints that will enforce Uniqueness as well.

```
ALTER TABLE schemaName.TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Relation PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(OwnerId , gizmosId);
```

Comment: I ran a sql query running this and it noted it ran successfully. is there a way to view my constraints on a column as it isn't showing up on in sql server management studio under the column I applied it to.

Comment: @dbollig try this `EXEC sp_helpconstraint 'dbo.tableName'`, I have modified the answer and changed the contraints to Primary Key from `Unique`.